# Checkboxes to insert value in specific cells

Tags: google-sheets, checkbox, google-sheets-formula, textjoin, ifs

[image]

I am trying to implement checkboxes to populate the Home and Away Teams name in B7 and D7 when its checked and cleared when unchecked.

The only formula i came up with and it doesn't work is =IF(F3,H3,"")

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(TEXTJOIN(; 1; IF(F3:F53; G3:G53; )))
```

Answer (score 0):

Accomplished what I wanted using `=iferror(IFS(F3=true,G3,F4=true,G4,F5=true,G5,F6=true,G6,F7=true,G7,F8=true,G8,F9=true,G9,F10=true,G10,F11=true,G11,F12=true,G12,F13=true,G13,F14=true,G14,F15=true,G15,F16=true,G16,F17=true,G17,F18=true,G18,F19=true,G19,F20=true,G20,F21=true,G21,F22=true,G22,F23=true,G23,F24=true,G24,F25=true,G25,F26=true,G26,F27=true,G27,F28=true,G28,F29=true,G29,F30=true,G30,F31=true,G31,F32=true,G32,F33=true,G33,F34=true,G34,F35=true,G35,F36=true,G36,F37=true,G37,F38=true,G38,F39=true,G39,F40=true,G40,F41=true,G41,F42=true,G42,F43=true,G43,F44=true,G44,F45=true,G45,F46=true,G46,F47=true,G47,F48=true,G48,F49=true,G49,F50=true,G50,F51=true,G51,F52=true,G52,F53=true,G53))`

Comment: this could be shortened by more than half

Comment: HAHA, yeah I imagine so, it got the job done. Appreciate you all though THANKS.